# Git clone stuck -- Blocked ports?

Tags: git, timeout, port

I am trying to download a library via `git`, and it seems to be getting stuck everytime on

```
'Cloning into [name]...'
```

no matter which library I try to connect to. 
My question is what *ports* does `git` use?
I guess my company could be blocking that port. Has anyone seen this before?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The ports are 22 (ssh), 443 (https) and 9418 for its own, read-only protocol. The protocol is the part of the repo URL before the `://`, except in the case of ssh, where the URL starts with `[user]@[host]:`.